# when use API Manager 1.5.0 and BAM 2.4.0,AM can not run.The database which used is mysql

Tags: mysql, wso2

### I used API Manager 1.5.0,BAM 2.4.0,and mysql as WSO2AM_STATS_DB. After configuratting AM and BAM,starting BAM.It is ok! But,when I start AM,It shows those logs:

INFO - AgentDS Successfully deployed Agent Client

INFO - EmbeddedRegistryService Configured Registry in 124ms

INFO - RegistryCoreServiceComponent Registry Mode    : READ-WRITE

INFO - UserStoreMgtDSComponent Carbon UserStoreMgtDSComponent activated successfully.

INFO - TaglibUriRule TLD skipped. URI: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles is already defined

WARN - CarbonServerManager Carbon initialization is delayed due to the following unsatisfied items:

WARN - CarbonServerManager Waiting for required OSGiAxis2Service: org.wso2.carbon.mediation.configadmin-4.2.0

WARN - CarbonServerManager Waiting for required OSGiAxis2Service: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway-1.2.0

WARN - CarbonServerManager Waiting for required OSGiAxis2Service: org.wso2.carbon.localentry-4.2.0

WARN - CarbonServerManager Carbon initialization is delayed due to the following unsatisfied items:

WARN - CarbonServerManager Waiting for required OSGiAxis2Service: org.wso2.carbon.mediation.configadmin-4.2.0

WARN - CarbonServerManager Waiting for required OSGiAxis2Service: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway-1.2.0

WARN - CarbonServerManager Waiting for required OSGiAxis2Service: org.wso2.carbon.localentry-4.2.0

WARN - CarbonServerManager Carbon initialization is delayed due to the following unsatisfied items:

WARN - CarbonServerManager Waiting for required OSGiAxis2Service: org.wso2.carbon.mediation.configadmin-4.2.0

WARN - CarbonServerManager Waiting for required OSGiAxis2Service: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway-1.2.0

WARN - CarbonServerManager Waiting for required OSGiAxis2Service: org.wso2.carbon.localentry-4.2.0

WARN - CarbonServerManager Carbon initialization is delayed due to the following unsatisfied items:

WARN - CarbonServerManager Waiting for required OSGiAxis2Service: org.wso2.carbon.mediation.configadmin-4.2.0

WARN - CarbonServerManager Waiting for required OSGiAxis2Service: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway-1.2.0

WARN - CarbonServerManager Waiting for required OSGiAxis2Service: org.wso2.carbon.localentry-4.2.0

### AM can not run, It always shows "Waiting for required OSGiAxis2Service....." . I do not know how to resolve it.

Comment: If I use H2,there is the same result!It also shows "wsiting for required OSGiAxis2Service...."

Comment: Did you follow this guide? http://docs.wso2.org/display/AM150/Monitoring+using+WSO2+BAM

Comment: Resolved!       I modified the configuration of wso2server.sh.Then starting AM and BAM is ok!I did like this:"-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m" is changed to "-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m".The most important is "-Xmx",you should enlarge it,of course,your vm should have enough memory.

Comment: So, you are saying, it was a memory issue?